# FAT filesystem analysis tool

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems, fat32, embedded

I have a dump a FAT file system.

Is there a windows tool I can use to analyse it, including:

1. Provide basic information (sector size etc.)
2. Validate the file system, basic corruption checking
3. Allow the files and directory structure to be viewed and possibly edited (i.e mounting as a windows partition)

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bo Brantén's FileDisk. From his [site](http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/):

> FileDisk is a virtual disk driver for Windows that uses one or more files to emulate physical disks. A console application is included that lets you dynamically mount and unmount files.

After mounting the image dump and assigning a drive letter to it, you can use the standard Windows tools with it (chkdsk, fsutil, etc) and view it in Explorer.

It's also nice to see that the latest version added support for 64-bit systems. One of the things I regretted the most when I switched from Windows x86 to x64 was that I couldn't use this little gem.